# I am trying to run npm run dev while installing auth ui in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, npm

```
Error: Cannot find module 'F:\vite\bin\vite.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path F:\A. WEB DESIGN & DEVELOPMENT\My Projects\SAIMUM\saimum
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c vite

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ataur\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-10-31T19_15_47_188Z-debug.log
```

npm install worked correctly, but npm run dev raise this errro. my project is new and the laravel version is Laravel v9.37.0 (PHP v8.1.10)

Answer (score 0):

Please, you don't name your projects using special characters (& etc.).
Your path: `F:\A. WEB DESIGN & DEVELOPMENT\My Projects\SAIMUM\saimum` and *&* contains.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're running the latest version of Node.js on your machine. I had this happen and my node version was 12. I believe it requires either 14 or 16 at minimum

Comment: I downloaded node.js with command. it should download updated version. is not it? why should it download downgraded version of it? and how to solve it?

Comment: just downloading and installing it won't switch it to the right version. I recommend using nvm and following the guides in this article: https://www.carlrippon.com/using-multiple-versions-of-node-on-windows/